# Voltage gradient in voltage difference across a resistor

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance, electrical

If I have a voltage difference V from terminal 1 to terminal 2 of a resistor.
I take an arbitrary point P along the resistor, between terminal 1 and terminal 2, and take terminal 1 as a voltage reference.
Does the voltage difference between the point P and terminal 1 increases from 0 at terminal 1 to V at terminal 2 ?
Is there a voltage gradient across a resistor ?

The question is about circuit theory in general.

Comment: for metal film, yes there will be a voltage gradient along a resistor. You can see this, using the tip of a scope probe, with the scope-calibration voltage passing thru the resistor.

Answer (score 2):

An **ideal** resistor is indivisible, so you can't really talk about voltages **inside** the resistor.

A **real** resistor comprises some kind of resistive material: a carbon slug, a long wire, a thin metal or carbon film, for example. If you could trace a path from one terminal of the resistor, across this resistive material, to the other terminal of the resistor then you would indeed see a voltage gradient.

Having said that, you shouldn't assume that there is a **linear** gradient as you move across any physical dimension of the resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Resistors are made in many different ways but consider a wire wound resistor.  As you move from your reference terminal 1 to terminal 2 you increase resistance and potential difference.